# <mat-label> Label Text is disappearing randomly

Tags: html, css, angular, material-ui, angular-material

I am using a < mat-label> tag for displaying Title Text. The label and text css class needs to be displayed (or hidden) based on where the component is being called from (which passes conditions)

```
<mat-label [class]="conditionA? 'label-h3' : conditionB? '' : 'label-h2'">{{ conditionA? 'TitleA' : (conditionC? 'TitleB' :'') }}</mat-label>
<mat-chip-list #chipList>
 ... some code here ..
</mat-chip-list>
```

The problem is that label is working fine for the first time but when I play around in application and come back, then title text is blank.
I have checked by printing conditions and text. They are correct and same for the first time and after I come back. The HTML element itself for the mat-label is not generated in the later case.

Comment: Need more information: css, values, how they change etc.

Comment: They change based on conditions which are accepted as @Input by the angular component.